# Finding "outliers" in a group

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am working with hospital discharge data. All hospitalizations (cases) with the same Patient_ID are supposed to be of the same person. However I figured out that there are Pat_ID's with different ages and both sexes.

Imagine I have a data set like this:

```
Case_ID <- 1:8
Pat_ID <- c(rep("1",4), rep("2",3),"3")
Sex <- c(rep(1,4), rep(2,2),1,1)
Age <- c(rep(33,3),76,rep(19,2),49,15)
Pat_File <- data.frame(Case_ID, Pat_ID, Sex,Age)

Case_ID Pat_ID Sex Age
1       1      1   33
2       1      1   33
3       1      1   33
4       1      1   76
5       2      2   19
6       2      2   19
7       2      1   49
8       3      1   15
```

It was relatively easy to identify Pat_ID's with cases that differ from each other. I found these ID's by calculating an average for age and/or sex (coded as 1 and 2) with help of the function aggregate and then calculated the difference between the average and age or sex. I would like to automatically remove/identify cases where age or sex deviate from the majority of the cases of a patient ID. In my example I would like to remove cases 4 and 7.

Comment: http://www.r-bloggers.com/finding-outliers-in-numerical-data/

Comment: that link is for identifying statistical outliers, not unusual cases which is the question of the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
library(data.table)
```

Using `Mode` from 
[Is there a built-in function for finding the mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/standard-library-function-in-r-for-finding-the-mode)

```
  Mode <- function(x) {
    ux <- unique(x)
    ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 }

setDT(Pat_File)[, .SD[Age==Mode(Age) & Sex==Mode(Sex)] , by=Pat_ID]
#    Pat_ID Case_ID Sex Age
#1:      1       1   1  33
#2:      1       2   1  33
#3:      1       3   1  33
#4:      2       5   2  19
#5:      2       6   2  19
#6:      3       8   1  15
```

Testing other cases,

```
 Pat_File$Sex[6] <- 1
 Pat_File$Age[4] <- 16
 setDT(Pat_File)[, .SD[Age==Mode(Age) & Sex==Mode(Sex)] , by=Pat_ID]
 #    Pat_ID Case_ID Sex Age
 #1:      1       1   1  33
 #2:      1       2   1  33
 #3:      1       3   1  33
 #4:      2       6   1  19
 #5:      3       8   1  15
```

Comment: If for instance the Age outlier for Pat_ID is 16 rather than 76, then this doesn't work.

Comment: Using `mode` instead of `mean` this now works for the case of checking ages. - Neat function.

Comment: @jalapic I think it should work now.  Tried by changing `Pat_File$Sex[6] <- 1;Pat_File$Age[4] <- 16`; Getting the same result as yours

Comment: I don't get this function, it all could be done just with `as.numeric(names(sort(-table(x)))[1])`

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Yes, that also works, I think `tabulate` might be a bit faster, not tested

Comment: Maybe, because `table` essentially calls `tabulate` but usually `table` is highly efficient.

Comment: This one works best for my 2.7 *10^6 row data set. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 2):

This method works, I believe, though I doubt it's the quickest or most efficient way.

Essentially I split the dataframe by your grouping variable.  Then I found the 'mode' for the variables you're concerned about.  Then we filtered those observations that didn't contain all of the modes.  We then stuck everything back together:

```
library(dplyr) # I used dplyr to 'filter' though you could do it another way
temp <- split(Pat_File, Pat_ID)

Mode.Sex <- lapply(temp, function(x) { temp1 <- table(as.vector(x$Sex)); names(temp1)[temp1 == max(temp1)]})

Mode.Age <- lapply(temp, function(x) { temp1 <- table(as.vector(x$Age)); names(temp1)[temp1 == max(temp1)]})

temp.f<-NULL
for(i in 1:length(temp)){
  temp.f[[i]] <- temp[[i]] %>% filter(Sex==Mode.Sex[[i]] & Age==Mode.Age[[i]])
}

do.call("rbind", temp.f)

#  Case_ID Pat_ID Sex Age
#1       1      1   1  33
#2       2      1   1  33
#3       3      1   1  33
#4       5      2   2  19
#5       6      2   2  19
#6       8      3   1  15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using the sqldf package: 
1) Create new dataframe (called data_groups) with unique groups based on Pat_ID, Sex, and Age
2) For each unique group, check Pat_ID against every other group and if the Pat_ID of one group matches another group, select the group with lower count and store in new vector (low_counts)
3) Take new datafame (data_groups) and take out Pat_IDs from new vector (low_counts) 
4) Recombine with Pat_File

Here is the code:

```
library(sqldf)

# Create new dataframe with unique groups based on Pat_ID, Sex, and Age
data_groups <- sqldf("SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM Pat_File GROUP BY Pat_ID, Sex, Age")
# Create New Vector to Store Pat_IDs with Sex and Age that differ from mode
low_counts <- vector()
# Unique groups
data_groups

for(i in 1:length(data_groups[,1])){
  for(j in 1:length(data_groups[,1])){
    if(i<j){
      k <- length(low_counts)+1
      result <- data_groups[i,2]==data_groups[j,2]
      if(is.na(result)){result <- FALSE}
      if(result==TRUE){
        if(data_groups[i,5]<data_groups[j,5]){low_counts[k] <- data_groups[i,1]}      
        else{low_counts[k] <- data_groups[j,1]}
      }
    }
  }
}

low_counts <- as.data.frame(low_counts)
# Take out lower counts
data_groups <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM data_groups WHERE Case_ID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM low_counts)")

Pat_File <- sqldf("SELECT Pat_File.Case_ID, Pat_File.Pat_ID, Pat_File.Sex, Pat_File.Age FROM data_groups, Pat_File WHERE data_groups.Pat_ID=Pat_File.Pat_ID AND data_groups.Sex=Pat_File.Sex AND data_groups.Age=Pat_File.Age ORDER BY Pat_File.Case_ID")

Pat_File
```

Which Provides the following results:

```
  Case_ID Pat_ID Sex Age
1       1      1   1  33
2       2      1   1  33
3       3      1   1  33
4       5      2   2  19
5       6      2   2  19
6       8      3   1  15
```